# how does a compiler assign which so version to use?

Tags: linux, symlink, dynamic-linking

I am trying to run an exe file in linux and this error message appears:

"error while loading shared libraries: libquickfix.so.14: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

I have the .so version of this file.

My question is where did it get the 14?  In my g++ command, i have -lquickfix

Comment: Is `libquickfix.so` a valid link?  Does it exist in `/usr/lib` or some other directory listed in `/etc/ld.so.conf`?  What is in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your compiler.  If the executable exists, then the compiler is finished.  The problem is with the configuration of `ldd`, the run-time linker.  Probably, the simplest solution is to ensure that the directory containing libquickfix.so.14 is listed in the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:}/path/to/lib
```

Comment: what's the deal with ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH+:} ?  shouldn't export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/lib work fine?

Comment: If LD_LIBRARY_PATH is empty, you do not want a `:`, but if it is non-empty you want the `:` to separate the new value.